# Classpath for ojdbc6.jar not detected after being added to .bashrc in ubuntu

Tags: java, oracle, ubuntu, jdbc, jar

i have added the ojdbc6.jar and the ojdbc6_g.jar file in the .bashrc but i keep getting the driver error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:259)
at jdbcdisplay.main(jdbcdisplay.java:17)
```

I have added the following Classpath to the .bashrc file for the ojdbc6.jar file:

```
export CLASSPATH=".:/home/shawnreese/Downloads/ojdbc6.jar:/home/shawnreese/Downloads/ojdbc6_g(1).jar"
```

The jar files are not even detected.They just keep showing the same error.On performing echo ${CLASSPATH} i get the jar file of opencsv.jar added in .bashrc.

```
 .:/home/shawnreese/Downloads/opencsv-2.3/deploy/opencsv-2.3.jar
```

I am using java version:

```
java version "1.8.0_20"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_20-b26)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.20-b23, mixed mode)
```

and Oracle 11g Release 2.

Comment: How do you start your application? Note that almost all ways of starting java (ie when using `-jar` or `-cp`) ignores the `CLASSPATH` environment variable

Comment: Try to compile like the following `java -cp "/home/shawnreese/Downloads/opencsv-2.3/deploy/opencsv-2.3.jar:/home/shawnreese/Downloads/ojdbc6.jar:."`. If the compilation goes through fine, then add the entry in the same order.

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel-I just run my applications from the terminal.

Comment: @learningloop-I did it and it returns cannot find or load main class jdbcdisplay